# Configure Scala for existing project in Intellij13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Note: before marking this as a duplicate:  Similar questions to this have been raised in the past: but it is my hope that some recent versions/ developments in Intellij may lead to a better conclusion.

The following screenshot shows that some basic Scala constructs are not being recognized:

[image]

Here is the scala libs in the project structure | global libraries:

[image]

Here is the overall project structure:

[image]

Comment: I've had this kind of thing happen with 13.  It turns out to be usually something like SCALA_HOME wasn't specified when I created the project, no Java SDK or somesuch

Comment: @Parasanger  Hi thanks for responding.  This is an existing maven project - specified simply as maven project. It should not be necessary to have the env variables set first -instead the question is how to configure an existing project to get IJ happy to serve scala.

Comment: sorry, never imported a scala/mvn project into intellij, just SBT.  Good luck!